# find the limit ?1

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

My attempt : lim (1+3x^2)^f(x)

```
              x→0

      i take f(x) = 5cotx + 2cosecx/x

                  = 5cosx/sinx  + 2/xsinx

                  = 5xcosx + 2 /xsinx
```

i don't know the further step  how to evaluate this limit...

Im confused ,pliz help me and tell me the solution,,

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$(1+3x^2)^{5\cot x+\frac{2\csc x}x}=\left((1+3x^2)^{1/3x^2}\right)^{\dfrac{3x^2(5x\cos x+2)}{x\sin x}}$$

Now $\dfrac{3x^2(5x\cos x+2)}{x\sin x}=\dfrac{3(5x\cos x+2)}{\dfrac{\sin x}x}$

Comment: thank u so much @ lab Bhattacharjee,,,,i got my answer e^6

Answer (score 0):

$$\newcommand{\l}[2]{\lim_{#1\to #2}}$$
You can use the formula

> $$\l{x}{0}(1+f(x))^{g(x)}=e^{\l{x}{0}f(x)g(x)}$$
>   For,
>   $$\l{x}{0}f(x)=0$$
>   $$\l{x}{0}g(x)=\infty$$

$$\l{x}{0}(1+3x^2)^{5\cot x+2\frac{\csc x}{x}}$$
$$\l{x}{0}e^{3x^2(5\csc x\cos x+2\frac{\csc x}{x})}$$
$$\l{x}{0}e^{3x\csc x(5x\cos x+2)}$$
$$\l{x}{0}e^{6\frac{x}{\sin x }}$$
$$e^{6}$$